# connect to tfs and download the files present in it VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to connect to TFS and download the files present in it. I am using VS2010 and tried the following code. But it seems I went wrong somewhere:

> "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method" for GetItem() and CopyTo() methods

My code is not downloading all the files.

C# Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "https://YourTfsUrl/tfs/YourTeamProjectCollection";
        string filePath = "C:\project\myfile.cs";

        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
        VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        Item item = versionControlServer.GetItem(filePath, VersionSpec.Latest);

        string fileString = string.Empty;

        using (Stream stream = item.DownloadFile())
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);


                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())))
                {
                    fileString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(fileString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Could anybody please help me out getting the proper approach?

Comment: _"But it seems I went wrong somewhere."_ - can you elaborate please?

Comment: I want to download all the files present in the TFS server. Even the new file which is added, should be downloaded. But my code is not downloading all the files. Also i am getting error "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method" for GetItem() and CopyTo() methods. @Roy

Comment: Thanks UserAR.  I have incorporated your comment into your question above.

Comment: Okay, Could I know the reason and solution for the same?? @Roy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
        string serverPath = "$/My Project/My SubFolder";
        string localPath = @"c:\temp\download";

        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
        VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        foreach (Item item in versionControlServer.GetItems(serverPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.Any, true).Items)
        {
            string target = Path.Combine(localPath, item.ServerItem.Substring(2));

            if (item.ItemType == ItemType.Folder && !Directory.Exists(target))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
            }
            else if (item.ItemType == ItemType.File)
            {
                item.DownloadFile(target);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain me the code snippet or "server path" and "local path" variables?