# Invalid Operation Exception, while downloading files from TFS to local folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a code to download files from TFS to local folder but getting an error :
**InvalidOperationException: the path $/My Project/Something is not a file**. As I am new to this concept, could you guys help me out how to deal with it??

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
    string serverPath = "$/My Project";
    string localPath = @"c:\temp\download";

    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
    VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    foreach (Item item in versionControlServer.GetItems(serverPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.Any, true).Items)
    {
        string target = Path.Combine(localPath, item.ServerItem.Substring(2));

        if (item.ItemType == ItemType.Folder && !Directory.Exists(target))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
        }
        else if (item.ItemType == ItemType.File)
        {
            item.DownloadFile(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I wrong in assigning the path or wrong in adding files to TFS?

Refered below links:

to add files to TFS "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/10/21/tutorial-getting-started-with-tfs-in-vs2010.aspx"

Code is taken from "[connect to tfs and download the files present in it VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453560/connect-to-tfs-and-download-the-files-present-in-it-vs2010/32454226#32454226)"

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: BTW looks like you're building this tool: http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/03/14/download-files-from-tfs-version-control-and-set-the-file-last-access-timestamp-to-the-file-s-last-check-in-time/

Comment: @jessehouwing, I want it to go to elseif part, wherein it says `item.ItemType` is not a file. So it is not downloading any files.

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes something like that but I don't mind creating a workspace also!!

Comment: If you don't mind creating a workspace, by far the easiest way is to create one, map the folders and then call Get on it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139316(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks :) @jessehouwing