# Download entire solution or specific branch from TFS to local folder

Tags: powershell, tfs

Hi all I got the below script to download a file from TFS, using powershell script, but I need to download entire solution how can I achieve that

```
cls
$tfsCollectionUrl = New-Object System.URI("http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection");
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfsCollection = Get-TfsServer $tfsCollectionUrl
$VersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$DestinationFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$VersionControl.DownloadFileByUrl('$/MyFirstProject/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/WebForm1.aspx.cs', $DestinationFile)

Invoke-Item $DestinationFile
```

Also this is not checking whether he is having permission to download , I would like to prompt for username and password instead of downloading directly. Can I achieve the same for bitbucket too if so how can I

Answer (score 1):

The same code converted to powershell

[connect to tfs and download the files present in it VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453560/connect-to-tfs-and-download-the-files-present-in-it-vs2010)

For credential use the above logic

```
Write-Host "Enter source location "
$sourceLocation = Read-Host

$tfsCollectionUrl = New-Object System.URI($sourceLocation);

Write-Host "Enter server path "
$serverPath = Read-Host

Write-Host "Enter local path to download"
$localPath = Read-Host

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfsCollection = Get-TfsServer $tfsCollectionUrl

$VersionControl = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$latest = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest
$recursionType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full
try
{

    foreach ($item in $VersionControl.GetItems($serverPath, $latest,$recursionType).Items)
    {
        $target =   [io.path]::Combine($localPath,$item.ServerItem.Substring(2))
        $exists=[System.IO.Directory]::Exists($target)

        if($item.ItemType -eq "Folder" -and !$exists)
        {
            New-Item $target -Type Directory
        }
        if($item.ItemType -eq "File")
        {
            $item.DownloadFile($target)
        }
    }
    Write-Host "`n Successfully downloaded all the files to the target folder: " $localPath -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to have a workspace mapping multiple projects and run the [tf get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/get-command) from Powershell.

You can also manage workspace with [tf workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workspace-command) command line.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that:

1. Create a workspace
2. Map a workspace
3. Get all files.

Sample code:

```
$tfsCollectionUrl = New-Object System.URI("[team project collection url");

$username="[user name]"
$password="[password]"
$domain="[domain]"
$cret = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain)
$teamProjectCollection=new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl,$cret)
$teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated()
$VersionControl = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$workspace = $VersionControl.CreateWorkspace("BasicSccExamplePS", $VersionControl.AuthorizedUser);
$workspace.Map("[file or folder server path, for example:$/TestTeam/FolderA]", "[local path]")
$workspace.Get()
```

You can find that it lets you to provide the credential, so you could let user to provide username, password, then connect to TFS with that account.

Regards