# How to download the files from TFS to our local folder using c# application code?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am a SSIS developer, but very new to C# coding. I have got a new requirement where I need to write a C# code to connect to TFS path and download the files from TFS to our local path or shared network.

I am using the below code which I found from the link below but it is not working as expected, can anyone suggest me where am I going wrong?

[connect to tfs and download the files present in it VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453560/connect-to-tfs-and-download-the-files-present-in-it-vs2010)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
    string serverPath = "$/My Project/My SubFolder";
    string localPath = @"c:\temp\download";

    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
    VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    foreach (Item item in versionControlServer.GetItems(serverPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.Any, true).Items)
    {
        string target = Path.Combine(localPath, item.ServerItem.Substring(2));

        if (item.ItemType == ItemType.Folder && !Directory.Exists(target))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
        }
        else if (item.ItemType == ItemType.File)
        {
            item.DownloadFile(target);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is looping through the files what I have on the TFS, but it doing nothing for item.DownloadFile(target); Please help me out with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to do this as opposed to mapping a workspace with `tf`?

Comment: My code is not about mapping the workspace, we need to download the files from the TFS and then deploy these files onto the server. That is our final goal.

Comment: then use a build and a release. This is built in functionality. You don't need to write any code.

Comment: We are currently using build and release in TFS, but it is only single SSIS project deployment. For each SSIS project we are queuing the build and it will release that particular project on to the server. But I have a c# code written to take all the ispac files from a folder and then deploy all of them in one go. So, now I want to implement additional code on top of it to take these ispac files from TFS directly and deploy on to the server.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting binaries into source control. Your builds should publish artifacts, then your release should reference the appropriate artifacts and deploy them. Again, this is **built in** functionality.

Comment: The in built TFS build and release functionality is limited when it comes to deploying the SSIS packages, we are looking for a way where we can deploy all our projects for that particular release in one go, instead of queuing each and every project we have. That is why we have built a c# code which can pull these projects at a time and deploy all of them using c# code.

Comment: I am using the C# code to deploy all the SSIS projects (Ispac files) from a shared drive and deploying on to the server, but instead of shared drive, I want to get these Ispac files directly from TFS and deploy onto the server. (that is the purpose of this post)

Comment: This question is asking to solve the wrong problem. If you're having a problem with the built-in build and release functionality that is specifically designed to solve the problem of building and deploying software, **ask about that problem**.

Comment: Well, I just want to see if there is a way we can just download the TFS files to local path/ shared path. I have even started with the code mentioned in my post, I just want a suggestion where I am going wrong, because the code listed in my post looping through all the files but it is not downloading to my given local path. This ask has been sidelined by asking why do I need it?

Comment: @Aparanjit this code works perfect on my side, do you get an error? do you have permissions to the Server Path?

Comment: I do have access to Server path, and I tested each line of the code by putting breakpoints, but once it reaches the item.DownloadFile(target); line, it is not downloading that file to my local path. And no errors at all.

Comment: Well to be precise, this code is working when I give the local path like "C:\SSIS\Downloads"; but if I give my shared drive complete location then it is not downloading, example "\\Shared003\Data\Test\SSIS\Downloads";